# Occurrence of braces when we use \cite versus \footcite within a \footnote

Tags: footnotes, biblatex-chicago, endnotes

Here is what we want. All footnotes must go at the endnotes (this part is done using endnotes package). Within footnotes two things can happen.

1. There is some text and a citation as opposed to only a citation. In the case of text and citation, we want full citation in braces within the footnote text (for an example of this, see the first citation in the sample file).
2. When we don't put any text in footnotes and only cite an article, that citation should appear without braces (example of this is the second citation). This is the desired output when there is not footnote text, but this is acheived by:

   ```
   \footnote{\cite{auth3}}
   ```

We have read that it is not recommended to use `\cite` within `\footnote`. We would like to use `\footnote{\footcite{auth3}}` but do not want the enclosing braces when there is no footnote text prior to \footcite

My query is that: How do I remove the braces around the footnote created using `\footcite`.

Please see the 3rd note on Page 6 of the sample output to see a footnote in braces.

[sample output](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1pX8X_p1x3xHpfK-bWiolDLDKGSKLEfJE)

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0.2in,%
        left=1in,right=1in,top=1.2in,bottom=1.2in,%
        footskip=.5in]{geometry}

\usepackage{makeidx}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\usepackage[notes,hyperref=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\renewcommand\nameyeardelim{, }
\bibliography{sample.bib}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}


\title{A catchy title}
\author{Auth 1 \and Auth 2}

\makeindex

\begin{document}
\maketitle\newpage
\tableofcontents\newpage

\frontmatter

\chapter{Intro}
Sample statement\footnote{Sample Sample satement of\footcite{auth2}    Sample satement sample statement in\footcite{auth1} and  in.s\footcite{auth2}}
Sample satement sample statementSample satement sample  statementSample satement sample statement of cite.   \footnote{\cite{auth3}}
Sample statement.\footnote{\footcite{auth1}}

\newpage
\theendnotes


\printbibliography

\small
\printindex

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general it is not recommended to use

```
\footnote{\cite{sigfridsson}}
```

for simple citations or citations with only short pre- and postnotes (your case 2), since the same could be achieved more semantically with

```
\footcite{sigfridsson}
```

or, if you have short notes, with

```
\footcite[See also][380-382]{sigfridsson}
```

It is then also quite easy to go from footnote citations to, say, parenthetical citations with a simple search-and-replace. Of course it would be *even better* to use `\autocite` in the first place and configure it to produce footnote citations. Then you can simply switch the citation style by changing one option.

If you have a normal footnote with text and want to add a citation to that footnote, there is absolutely no issue with using `\cite` within `\footnote`, though.

```
\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum. \cite{sigfridsson}}
```

It would be a bit odd to use `\footcite` within a `\footnote` since `\footcite` is supposed to produce a new footnote. So you would be producing a footnote from within another footnote. Since LaTeX does not allow this anyway by default, `biblatex` then just goes over to using round brackets around the citation.

---

`biblatex-chicago`'s default `\autocite` (`\smartcite`) behaves like `\footcite` in the text and like `\cite` if it is already in a footnote. This should give you exactly the behaviour you want. So I suggest you use `\autocite` everywhere.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\frontmatter

\chapter{Intro}
Sample statement\footnote{Sample Sample satement of\autocite{sigfridsson}.
  Sample satement sample statement in\autocite{nussbaum}
  and in \autocite{sigfridsson}.}
Sample satement sample statementSample satement sample  statementSample
satement sample statement of cite.\autocite{worman}
Sample statement.\autocite{nussbaum}

\theendnotes
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Endnotes without round brackets.]

Comment: Thanks a lot @moewe. So helpful. Clears all doubt and solves the problem. Thank you.